# Python 3.4/Tkinter cross class variable accessing

Tags: python, tkinter

```
__author__ = 'rvncpn'

import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


class layOut(tkinter.Tk):
    volts = 0
    amps = 0
    ohms = 0

    def updizzle(self):
        layOut.volts = layOut.ve.get()
        layOut.amps = layOut.ie.get()
        layOut.ohms = layOut.re.get()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(columns=3, rows=3, sticky='nsew')
        tkinter.Tk.title(self, 'Ohms Law v2')

        v = ttk.Label(container, text='Volts')
        v.grid(column=0, row=0)

        i = ttk.Label(container, text='Amperes')
        i.grid(column=1, row=0)

        r = ttk.Label(container, text='Ohms')
        r.grid(column=2, row=0)

        ve = ttk.Entry(container)
        ve.grid(column=0, row=1)

        ie = ttk.Entry(container)
        ie.grid(column=1, row=1)

        re = ttk.Entry(container)
        re.grid(column=2, row=1)

        button = ttk.Button(container, text='Button', command=layOut.updizzle)
        button.grid(column=2, row=2,pady=6)

        answer = ttk.Label(container, text='32095782hirjfkebfesfme')
        answer.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)


class ohms(layOut):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = layOut.volts
        self.i = layOut.amps
        self.r = layOut.ohms
        self.w = []

    def sorter(self):
        if self.v > 0:
            self.w.append('volts')
        if self.i > 0:
            self.w.append('amps')
        if self.r > 0:
            self.w.append('ohms')

    def listCheck(self):
        if 'volts' in self.w and 'amps' in self.w and 'ohms' in self.w:
            print('you must leave one of the perimeter empty')
        elif 'volts' in self.w and 'amps' in self.w:
            print('resistance =', self.v / self.i)
        elif 'volts' in self.w and 'ohms' in self.w:
            print('amps =', self.i / self.i)
        elif 'amps' in self.w and 'ohms' in self.w:
            print('volts=', self.i * self.r)
        else:
            pass


app = layOut()
app.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: updizzle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Can not figure this out for the life of me I know its going to be something simple and I'm going to kick myself.

Comment: You should really post the *full* traceback, not just the exception. Can you try and reduce this to a small sample the reproduces the problem? What is the code supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the *unbound method*, where you should use `self` to create a bound method. Replace:

```
button = ttk.Button(container, text='Button', command=layOut.updizzle)
```

with:

```
button = ttk.Button(container, text='Button', command=self.updizzle)
```

Note that none of these items is stored on your instance or class; there is no `layOut.ve`, `layOut.ie` or `layOut.re` being set, because you left `ve`, `ie` and `re` as locals. Best set those on the *instance* (so on `self`), then look them up on `self` again in `updizzle`:

```
class layOut(tkinter.Tk):
    volts = 0
    amps = 0
    ohms = 0

    def updizzle(self):
        self.volts = self.ve.get()
        self.amps = self.ie.get()
        self.ohms = self.re.get()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(columns=3, rows=3, sticky='nsew')
        tkinter.Tk.title(self, 'Ohms Law v2')

        v = ttk.Label(container, text='Volts')
        v.grid(column=0, row=0)

        i = ttk.Label(container, text='Amperes')
        i.grid(column=1, row=0)

        r = ttk.Label(container, text='Ohms')
        r.grid(column=2, row=0)

        self.ve = ttk.Entry(container)
        self.ve.grid(column=0, row=1)

        self.ie = ttk.Entry(container)
        self.ie.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.re = ttk.Entry(container)
        self.re.grid(column=2, row=1)

        button = ttk.Button(container, text='Button', command=layOut.updizzle)
        button.grid(column=2, row=2,pady=6)

        answer = ttk.Label(container, text='32095782hirjfkebfesfme')
        answer.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2)
```